# mysql external shell command to get GeoIP Information from an IP address

Tags: mysql, shell, command-line, external, geoip

I have geoiplookup installed on Centos 7 and I'd like to select an IP from a mysql table and then get the location of an IP address from the command line.

For example, I can type ! geoiplookup' 123.45.36.35 in mysql and get the city, country, etc.

I could download the data from [MaxMind](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/) and then upload it to mysql and run a query as mentioned on this [site](https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/06/01/implementing-efficient-geo-ip-location-system-in-mysql/) or this [site](http://mrjoy.com/2013/09/04/fast-geoip-queries-in-mysql/) but I do not want to maintain and update another table monthly.  Is this the best solution?

This [link](https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-python/tree/master/examples) shows several python examples that I have used in fail2ban logs.

Id like to do something like this:

```
SELECT udf_geoip_lookup(ip) AS 'City',  
     udf_geoip_lookup(ip) AS 'State'
     udf_geoip_lookup(ip) AS 'Region
FROM table-name
 ;
```

3 functions calls would be too much.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `udf_geoip_lookup` (ip varchar(15))
RETURNS varchar(100)
BEGIN

      SET @sql = CONCAT('\! geoiplookup', @ip);
      -- I need to parse the city, region, country etc, somehow.
      PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;   

RETURN @sql;
END;
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, if you want to use the geoiplookup utility and keep up-to-date IP info you would need to periodically (monthly), download and maintain the IP updates from **MaxMind** (with a cron job).

What you may want to do instead is to call the `curl` utility, and retrieve data from the super cool [ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io/) website:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io/47.144.148.253
{
  "ip": "47.144.148.253",
  "city": "Hermosa Beach",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "33.8622,-118.3990",
  "org": "AS5650 Frontier Communications of America, Inc.",
  "postal": "90254"
}
```

Then you would need to parse that JSON output.  But you can also pass a GET parameter with the ip address and get exactly what you want to retrieve.

For example, I ran `curl` with these parameters:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io/47.144.148.253/country
US
$ curl ipinfo.io/47.144.148.253/region
California
$ curl ipinfo.io/47.144.148.253/city
Hermosa Beach
```

So your SQL functions would be something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `curl_lookup_country` (ip varchar(15))
RETURNS varchar(100)
BEGIN
      SET @sql = CONCAT('\! curl', 'ipinfo.io/',@ip,'/country');
      PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;   // country
RETURN @sql;
END;

CREATE FUNCTION `curl_lookup_region` (ip varchar(15))
RETURNS varchar(100)
BEGIN
      SET @sql = CONCAT('\! curl', 'ipinfo.io/',@ip,'/region');
      PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;   // region or state
RETURN @sql;
END;

CREATE FUNCTION `curl_lookup_city` (ip varchar(15))
RETURNS varchar(100)
BEGIN
      SET @sql = CONCAT('\! curl', 'ipinfo.io/',@ip,'/city');
      PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;   // city
RETURN @sql;
END;
```

And your SQL query would be:

```
SELECT curl_lookup_country(ip) AS 'Country',  
     curl_lookup_region(ip) AS 'State'
     curl_lookup_city(ip) AS 'City
FROM table-name
```

This way you do not have to parse the JSON output.

**But I must warn you**:  this **DOES** make 3 HTTP requests for **each** IP address query.  If it is a large table it would be a pretty big performance hit to do 3 HTTP curl requests for each row in the table.

If you need to access this IP data many times you should consider creating country, region and city columns in the original table along with the IP address, then run an UPDATE statement to only update rows where these columns are empty, and fill them with your groovy new **curl_lookup_xxx** functions.

Something like this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET country = curl_lookup_country(ip),
    region = curl_lookup_region(ip),
    city = curl_lookup_city(ip)
WHERE ip IS NOT NULL AND
  (country IS NULL OR
   region IS NULL OR
   city IS NULL)
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks.  I found a function at this link but I did not have luck compiling it.  https://github.com/mjradwin/geoip-udf

Comment: I have a cronjob set up to download the files from maxmind, but I did not want to import the maxmind csv files into mysql because I didn't want someone to see the database password if they got access to the script.  I assume there is a secure way to do it but I have not found it yet.  I guess I could create a user with only permissions to update that particular table.

Comment: If your cron script is not accessible from your website, then no one can get access to your db password that way.  You could also set permissions on the script to only be accessible to the root user.  If someone gets your account password then certainly they may be able to view the script and get your db password.  But if someone gets your account password, you've got bigger problems to deal with.

Comment: Thanks!  I do everything form the command line (ssh on custom port) and not through a website.  So that will work.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do this on the database level in efficient way, feel free to read our latest blog.

we basically transformed the IP range dataset into 3 key-value dataset per octet (without the 4th), and it worked well on over 10MM records through SQL in multiple warehouses.

We found out that our clients mostly ask for countries or US states and we designed our datasets to those specific needs ONLY.

you can read more about it here:
https://cloudinary.com/blog/identifying_countries_by_ip_address_in_columnar_databases_through_sql

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the article.